# Problem with writing new CSV-File in Python (it only shows my header)

Tags: python, csv

i have this csv_file that i am working with in Python.

```
import csv 
videogames_liste = []

with open('vgsales.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    next(csv_reader)
   
    for line in csv_reader:
        videogames_liste.append(line) here
```

I already filtered out the records of videogames in 2008 and saved them to a list.

```
daten_2008 = []
for record in videogames_liste:
    if record["Year"] == "2008":
        #print(record["Name"], record["Year"])
        daten_2008.append(record)
```

Now i want to create a new file with this list. But when i do this, i get a new csv_file that only shows my header line hundreds of times, not the records of 2008.

```
with open('daten_2008.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
    writer.writerows(daten_2008)
```

I would be very thankful for help.

I tried DictWriter which also didn't work.

Comment: If `'vgsales.csv'` has a header, then doing `next(csv_reader)` is going to skip the first data row as `csv.DictReader()` without `fieldnames` explicitly set will assume the first row is the header and use it for the field names and then automatically skip to the first data row. Doing `next(csv_reader)`  will then skip over that row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) and giving it a *list of dictionnaries*.

> Writer objects (DictWriter instances and objects returned by the
> writer() function) have the following public methods. **A row must be an
> iterable of strings or numbers for Writer objects and a dictionary
> mapping fieldnames to strings or numbers (by passing them through
> str() first) for DictWriter objects.** Note that complex numbers are
> written out surrounded by parens. This may cause some problems for
> other programs which read CSV files (assuming they support complex
> numbers at all).
>
> *Source* : [[Writer Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects)]

Use this instead to fix your code :

```
with open('daten_2008.txt', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    # writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ',') # (-) remove this line
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=daten_2008[0].keys()) # (+) add this line
    writer.writeheader() # (+) add this line
    writer.writerows(daten_2008)
```

You can go further and make your full code shorter :

```
import csv

with open("vgsales.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    daten_2008 = [row for row in reader if row["Year"] == "2008"]

with open("daten_2008.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=daten_2008[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(daten_2008)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use csv.DictWriter() here by first specifying all the column names

```
fieldnames = ['Name', 'Year']
with open('daten_2008.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(daten_2008)
```